# Azure resource access management and its relation with tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure ARM handles identity requirements for the requests it receives through Azure AD. The requesting user should be a valid Azure AD user with a valid identity and authorization roles. The azure subscription for which the request is made should comply to deployment limits and biling policies.

There is a role of Azure Tenant that is associated with requesting user and Subscription. What role these tenants play and what is the workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by the role of the Azure tenant in this context, but you can assign roles at the tenant scope and that's what the ARM template documentation describes. For example, you can assign an Owner role to a user at the tenant scope so that the user is an Owner of the tenant. As for the relationship between tenants and subscriptions, multiple subscriptions can trust the same Azure AD tenant, but each subscription can only trust a single tenant. You can [associate a subscription with a tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory) by logging in and selecting the Subscription, and then changing the directory. With a Global Admin or User Admin role, you can [add or remove users from your tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory).

As I'm sure you already know, an Azure tenant is a dedicated and trusted instance of Azure AD. Typically, each tenant represents a single organization. The words "tenant" and "directory" are used interchangeably. The tenant is an account in Azure that comes with a subdomain and an associated Azure Active Directory. In order to use an Azure Active Directory you need to become a tenant within the system. So a tenant is basically securing a .onmicrosoft.com subdomain. At that point you would have one account registered in your Azure AD.

So in the context of the ARM template, you need an Azure tenant to house your users and link to your subscriptions.

Comment: Referring to the doc, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/govern/resource-consistency/resource-access-management, there are two groups of tenants one associated with Users and the other associated with Subscriptions. Why there are two groups of tenants in the figure 9 ?  Is it because subscription tenant users want their subscription to be managed by users of another tenant ?

Answer (score 0):

A tenant represents an organization in Azure Active Directory. It's a dedicated Azure AD service instance that an organization receives and owns when it signs up for a Microsoft cloud service such as Azure, Microsoft Intune, or Microsoft 365. Each Azure AD tenant is distinct and separate from other Azure AD tenants. Once you have an Azure AD tenant, you can define an application and assign it permissions so it can call REST APIs. Your organization may already have an Azure AD tenant that you can use for your application.

In Azure AD, users are segmented into tenants. A tenant is a logical construct that represents a secure, dedicated instance of Azure AD typically associated with an organization. Each subscription is associated with an Azure AD tenant. Next, the ARM checks whether the user has sufficient permission to access a resource using Azure RBAC (Role based Access Control) which manages the permissions. An Azure role specifies a set of permissions a user may take on a specific resource. Next, the resource request is checked against an Azure Resource Policy which are defined to allow specific operations for a specific resource. Next, ARM checks the Azure subscription limit for the specific resources in that subscription for resource groups. And finally, the financial commitment associated with the subscription is checked as a final control before deploying the resource for management through the ARM.

[ARM flow and working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHLg3.jpg)

Please find the below Microsoft documentation for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/govern/resource-consistency/resource-access-management

Thanking you,